# How to loop over all objects with a specific name in vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am making a game in PowerPoint with vba and I want to loop over all the objects with the name "collider" but it does not work.

```
Sub getCollision()

Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim curShape As Shape

For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Debug.Print curSlide.SlideNumber
    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes


    If curShape.Name = collider Then
        curShape.Left = 10
    Debug.Print curShape.Name

    Next curShape
Next curSlide

End Sub
```

Comment: `If curShape.Name = "collider" Then` if "collider" is the literal name of the shape.

Comment: You need to provide more than just "does not work", what exactly does not work? Did you get any error on any line? Try changing `curShape.Name = collider`  to `curShape.Name = "collider"`

Comment: Two things that will save you a great deal of trouble in the future:  Add Option Explicit to the top of every module. In the VBA IDE, choose Tools | Options and checkmark Require Variable Declaration to have VBA automatically add this. With that in place, you'd have gotten an error about collider (not in quotes) being an undeclared variable.  Next, it's a time saver to compile your code before you try to run it. That'll also pinpoint errors.  Debug | Compile VBA Project

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the If function not ending properly with end if, it will cause debug issue when execution.

```
      If curShape.Name = collider Then
            curShape.Left = 10
        Debug.Print curShape.Name
   end if
```

2. By change the shape.name to correct one with quotation mark, such as curShape.Name = "Hello", then it work properly in my case, you can check the name of the shape in arrange>selection panel in Powerpoint

[image]